# Dealing with the Diamond Problem in Python: Implementing Multiple Inheritance Safely

Tags: python-3.x, class, object, oop, inheritance

I'm working on a project where I need to implement multiple inheritance in Python, and I'm concerned about encountering the "diamond problem." I want to make sure I handle it properly to avoid unexpected behavior in my code.

I have a class hierarchy that involves multiple inheritance, and I'm worried about potential conflicts and ambiguities that may arise due to the diamond problem. Specifically, I have classes A, B, and C, where B and C both inherit from A, and I want to create a class D that inherits from both B and C.

class A:
def method(self):
print("A method")

class B(A):
def method(self):
print("B method")

class C(A):
def method(self):
print("C method")

class D(B, C):
pass
I want to ensure that the method in class D behaves as expected and doesn't lead to unexpected behavior due to the diamond problem. What is the recommended approach to handle this situation in Python?

Comment: All of your classes need to _cooperate_. Call `super().method()` in each one.